# How would one separate cells with numerous names and emails to correspond to each other in individual rows?

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm struggling to get something like this...
[image: issue]

Into something like this...
[image: issue]

I know Google Sheets offers the ability to split the text into columns, but I don't quite get how to then transpose that data under the first row and then get the names to match.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
 TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(IF(LEN(A2:A), A2:A&",", ),,999^99), ","))),
 TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(IF(LEN(B2:B), B2:B&",", ),,999^99), ",")))})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic. In a limited test, it produced the results I was looking for, but on the full sheet, I'm seeing this error. Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 6714. Actual: 11556. Any idea what that might be in regards to?

Comment: To add to this, there's some rows where there might be two names and four emails. I assume that's creating the mismatch error. Could it be possible to fill on data to create blank cells for those that don't have a corresponding info?

Comment: the error means that column A has less stuff than column B

Answer (score 0):

e.g.,

`=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1, ","))`.

`SPLIT` will split the text across columns. `TRANSPOSE` will transpose the data into rows.